# Need help to solve $\int 1/\sqrt{u^2-c^2u}\ du$

Tags: integration

Is there an elegant way to solve the above integral? I don't have a good idea and wolfram alpha gives me a very complicated solution with hundreds of substitutions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$
u^2-c^2u = \left(u-\frac{c^2}{2}\right)^2 - \frac{c^4}{4}
$$
set $v = \frac{u-\frac{c^2}{2}}{c^2/2}$ we can write your integral as
$$
\int \sqrt{v^2-1}\ dv
$$

Now solving the new (edited) question we can find a similar transform.
$$
\int \frac{1}{\sqrt{v^2-1}}\ dv 
$$
still admits the same sub $v = \sec t$ we find
$$
\int \sec t\ dt
$$

Comment: Now... how does one solve the remaining integral...?

Comment: Try substituting $v = \sec t$

Comment: as long as one can compute $\int \sec t dt$ you will be fine - In fact that is a cool school calculus question.

Comment: I recommend using `\ ` (with an invisible space after the slash) to separate the `dv` part from the integrand.

Comment: @simpleart forgive my laziness.

Comment: Thank you chinny.  These looks similar to the first steps suggested by Wolfram alpha before things get really crazy.  Unfortunately I made a small mistake in my integrand.however, the approach should be very similar

Comment: Ok - I have missed some steps. But if WA produces the steps then this answer is quite redundant . Also, check the transforms from $u\to v$

Comment: @SimpleArt  Is this the time or place to "educate" about using (better than you suggest `\,` to separate $dx$ from the integral?  Just please don't try to act like your a know it all, when it's clear you don't "know it all."  Do you want me to be hangin' round your answers in order to "nit-pik" (which is exactly what you did here!)?

Comment: @amWhy Just a thought, and it seems as though the answer was pretty much answered by then.